# Cannot ping from a Linux machine to Windows machine

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, ping

I am trying to ping from one Linux machine to a Windows 10 machine on the same LAN network, but the ping process is stuck and does not show status.

From a second Linux machine and other Windows 10 machines, I can connect to this specific Windows 10 machine, so the machine's ports are open.

I wonder what could be the problem and how to approach it for a solution?

Comment: Can the first Linux machine ping all other computers except the problem one?

Comment: Answer to ping is not compulsory, some firewall on the ping target could disable it. Can it be pinged from other machines?

Comment: By default, windows firewall blocks ICMP.  You can disable the firewall on the windows machine to validate.

Comment: The first machine can ping all other machines, and the pinged machine can also be pinged from other machines as well.

Comment: I am still looking for a solution. Searched a lot on the web and here in SuperUser but there is no solution. Not only ping, of course, ssh does not work as well, even if it works back and forth with other machines and this Windows 10 one. I guess it is a Linux problem, rather than a Windows 10 problem, but this is really baffling.